# How to test the triggering of an event in a service in Grails 3.2?

Tags: events, grails, spock

I am running on Grails 3.2.5 and implemented a simple service. The service has a private and a public method. The private method triggers the notify method of the EventBus (provided by the Events trait).

```
@Transactional
class SyncService {
    def processQueue() {
        checkStatus(true)
    }

    private checkStatus(status) {
       if(status) {
           def model = [...]
           notify "status.completed", model
       }
    }
}
```

How can I write a unit test for this service, which checks if the notification has been triggered? The following implementation does not work:

```
@TestFor(SyncService)
class SyncServiceSpec extends Specification {

    void "test if notification is triggerd() {
        when:
            service.processQueue()

        then: "notification should be triggered"
            1 * service.notify(_)

    }
}
```

The test fails with the following output:

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * service.notify(_)   (0 invocations)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You could mock the event bus and perform interaction testing on the mock (tested in 3.2.11)

```
@TestFor(SyncService)
class SyncServiceSpec extends Specification {

  void 'test if notification is triggered'() {
    given: 'a mocked event bus'
    EventBus eventBusMock = Mock(EventBus)
    service.eventBus = eventBusMock

    when:
    service.processQueue()

    then: 'event bus is notified once'
    1 * eventBusMock.notify(*_)  //<--- you could get more specific with your arguments if you want

  }
}
```

Comment: Should the then clause instead specify `1 * service.eventBus.notify(*_)`?

Comment: Additionally, this appears to throw a `groovy.lang.ReadOnlyPropertyException` exception.

Answer (score 1):

The following expression:

```
1 * service.notify(_)
```

Means the single invocation of *notify* method with any single argument.

Try this:

```
1 * service.notify(*_)
```

PS Is there any additional info after the "Too few invocations for:" message? Any examples of what has been invoked?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have tried this but still receive the same message. Yes, there is an additional info that the method processQueue has been invoked once. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered a workaround in order to test the event. Instead of checking if the notify method is triggered, I test if the event is triggered using the on method. Therefore, in my test class I have something like:

```
@TestFor(SyncService)
class SyncServiceSpec extends Specification {

    void "test if notification is triggerd() {
        when:
            def eventResponse = null
            service.processQueue()
            service.on('status.completed') { data ->
                eventResponse = data
            }


        then: "notification should be triggered"
            eventResponse != null

    }
}
```